# how to capture selected tabs in TabSelect jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to implement Tabselect plugin(http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/tabselect.php) in my web form, I am trying to do two things but unable to figure out how to do.

1)when we have many values in tab, i like to add linebreak and display rest of the tabs in next line. 
2)Capture the selected tabs when the form is submitted.(not sure where to mention name/id tag and capture the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yun97ecf/1/

**1) when we have many values in tab, i like to add linebreak and display rest of the tabs in next line.**

change container from SPAN in DIV

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id="langtabs"></div> 
</div>
```

in CSS: add style width for container. for example 200px

```
#langtabs{width:200px}/* new */
```

and add style for div.demo span

```
display: inline-block;/* new */
```

**2) Capture the selected tabs when the form is submitted.(not sure where to mention name/id tag and capture the same)**

In form add input field.

```
<form id="form_lang">

    <input type="text" name="input_select_lang" id="input_select_lang" />
    <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Bind an event handler to the "submit". [submit function](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$('#form_lang').submit(function(){

        var select_lang='';

        // ## finding all selected tabs. (span with class active)
        $('#langtabs span.active').each(function(){
            var lang=$(this).text();
            // ## put all selected tabs in variable
            select_lang+=','+lang;
        })
        //## removing first comma
        select_lang=select_lang.substr(1);

        //## set input field before submit
        $('#input_select_lang').val(select_lang);        
})
```